# How to play background music with swift 2.0?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

HI I am new to swift and ios development. My code was working up until I've updated to Swift 2.0, I've used swift migrating tool, but I still can't figure out how to sort and fix my code. Please help!

```
import AVFoundation

var backgroundMusicP: AVAudioPlayer!

func playBackgroundMusic(filename: String) {
    let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(
        filename, withExtension: nil)
    if (url == nil) {
        print("Could not find file: \(filename)")
        return
    }

    var error: NSError?

    do {

        backgroundMusicP = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url!)
    } catch {

        backgroundMusicP == nil
    }
    if backgroundMusicP == nil {
        print("Could not create audio player: \(error)")
        return
    }

    backgroundMusicP.numberOfLoops = -1
    backgroundMusicP.prepareToPlay()
    backgroundMusicP.play()
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are talking about ?

Comment: Swift 2.0 introduced new error handling system. Dharmesh Kheni answer below is right.

Comment: It's usually a good idea to read the Xcode release notes when upgrading a major version and translating Swift Code. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc7_release_notes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH5-SW1

Comment: Well, apparently the above code does already use the new error handling model with do-try-catch, and it does compile with Swift 2. There are logical errors though, such as `backgroundMusicP == nil`.

Comment: Thanks for you replies, I will try the below code later on today.

Comment: Martine R: backgroudMusicP is not a logical error, its a variable of type  AVAudioPlayer!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Updated function for swift 2.0:

```
import AVFoundation

var backgroundMusicPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

func playBackgroundMusic(filename: String) {
    let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(filename, withExtension: nil)
    guard let newURL = url else {
        print("Could not find file: \(filename)")
        return
    }
    do {
        backgroundMusicPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: newURL)
        backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
        backgroundMusicPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        backgroundMusicPlayer.play()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.description)
    }
}
```

Use it this way:

```
playBackgroundMusic("yourFileName.mp3")
```

Comment: Where it says (filename, withExtension: nil), should I change that? Also, where it says playBackgroundMusic, I added my filename, but now Xcode wants a comma. Then it says it should be deleted. It keeps giving me those errors in a loop.

Comment: @spadaroapps, you should not change any of the above codes; just use the function as stated above.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable a session also for background playing capability.

```
func enableBackgroundPlaying(_ enable: Bool) throws {
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(enable)
        } catch {
            throw error
        }
    } catch {
        throw error
    }
}
```