# AV Foundation Transition Music Stopping

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I am using the following code to play music. It plays well :)

```
 var backgroundMusicPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    func playBackgroundMusic(filename: String) {
        let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(filename, withExtension: nil)
        guard let newURL = url else {
            print("Could not find file: \(filename)")
            return
        }
        do {
            backgroundMusicPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: newURL)
            backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
            backgroundMusicPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            backgroundMusicPlayer.play()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.description)
        }
    }

 playBackgroundMusic("music.wav")
```

However, I'd like to be able to keep the music playing only through certain transitions. Is this possible?

Cheers :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to play background music with swift 2.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32882737/how-to-play-background-music-with-swift-2-0)

Comment: to stop SKAudioNode,  you should be able to just pause it

Comment: Thanks Whirlwind. It was a duplicate. However, i have a new problem now. See edit above :)

Cheers :)

Comment: is `func playBackgroundMusic` inside another function?

Comment: Thank you for your help! Fixed it! I have editing the above question :)